# "Thumbnail could not be created for the image" on virtual machine

Tags: image, uploads, permissions

I am running ExpressionEngine inside of a [Vagrant virtual machine](http://www.vagrantup.com/). When trying to upload an image, I get the following error:

*Thumbnail could not be created for the image. Please make sure the thumbnail directory is writable.*

The image is uploaded to the "uploads" folder, but never gets past the point of creating the thumbnail. The _thumbs directory has 777 permissions and is owned by apache and inside the apache group. What could the problem be?

Comment: What's the server path and url to your upload directory? Make sure that both have a trailing slash... This has caused some issues for me before.